# Displaying JSON data in HTML table using angularjs ng-repeat directive

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, html

I am having trouble displaying the following json data in my html table using angular js ng-repeat directive

```
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th ng-repeat="(header, value) in gridheader">{{value}}</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr ng-repeat="row  in data">
      <span ng-repeat="r  in row track by $index" >
  <td>{{row[r].TrnId}}</td>
  <td>{{row[r].TrnDate}}</td>
  <td>{{row[r].SavingsMonth}}</td>
  <td>{{row[r].SavingsYear}}</td>
  <td>{{row[r].AccountName}}</td>
  <td>{{row[r].SavingsAdded}}</td>
  <td>{{row[r].SavingsRemoved}}</td>
  <td>{{row[r].SavingsRunningBalance}}</td>
      </span>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

I am picking this Json data from an angular JS controller and the returned from the resolve object is as shown below. This has really taken me whirlwind of sleepless nights  to decipher but all in vain
the Json Data:

```
   {
"rows": [
    {
        "TrnId": 217,
        "TrnDate": "2016-12-30T21:00:00.000Z",
        "SavingsMonth": "DECEMBER",
        "SavingsYear": "2016",
        "AccountName": "ABELUN STEPHENSON",
        "SavingsAdded": "3100000.0",
        "SavingsRemoved": "50000",
        "SavingsRunningBalance": "3050000"
    },
    {
        "TrnId": 218,
        "TrnDate": "2016-12-30T21:00:00.000Z",
        "SavingsMonth": "DECEMBER",
        "SavingsYear": "2016",
        "AccountName": "ACAN MOLLY NINA",
        "SavingsAdded": "3100000.0",
        "SavingsRemoved": "50000",
        "SavingsRunningBalance": "3050000"
    },
    {
        "TrnId": 219,
        "TrnDate": "2016-12-30T21:00:00.000Z",
        "SavingsMonth": "DECEMBER",
        "SavingsYear": "2016",
        "AccountName": "ADONYO HARRIET TIWAALI",
        "SavingsAdded": "5100000.0",
        "SavingsRemoved": "-",
        "SavingsRunningBalance": "5100000"
    },

    {
        "TrnId": 6558,
        "TrnDate": "2018-12-30T21:00:00.000Z",
        "SavingsMonth": "DECEMBER",
        "SavingsYear": "2018",
        "AccountName": "SANYA BRIAN",
        "SavingsAdded": "-",
        "SavingsRemoved": "45000.0",
        "SavingsRunningBalance": "205000.0"
    }
]
}
```

I have tried all possible ways but in vain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your json is stored in a variable $scope.data in your controller, the following code should work:

```
 <thead>
 <tr>
  <th ng-repeat="(header, value) in gridheader">{{value}}</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr ng-repeat="row  in data.rows">
  <td>{{row.TrnId}}</td>
  <td>{{row.TrnDate}}</td>
  <td>{{row.SavingsMonth}}</td>
  <td>{{row.SavingsYear}}</td>
  <td>{{row.AccountName}}</td>
  <td>{{row.SavingsAdded}}</td>
  <td>{{row.SavingsRemoved}}</td>
  <td>{{row.SavingsRunningBalance}}</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: It seems obvious that it should really work but incidentally it is not work. I really don't know what am doing wrongly

Comment: On your code you're doing an ng-repeat on data and not data.rows

Comment: <div>
<!-- {{data.rows}} -->


<thead>
        <tr>
         <th ng-repeat="(header, value) in gridheader">{{value}}</th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row  in data.rows">
         <td>{{row.TrnId}}</td>
         <td>{{row.TrnDate}}</td>
         <td>{{row.SavingsMonth}}</td>
         <td>{{row.SavingsYear}}</td>
         <td>{{row.AccountName}}</td>
         <td>{{row.SavingsAdded}}</td>
         <td>{{row.SavingsRemoved}}</td>
         <td>{{row.SavingsRunningBalance}}</td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
</div> Just like you edited

Comment: It's actually working, i had omitted the <table></table>, thanks so much